Where is 'new BrowserWindow()' in Angular Electron application
I try to rewrite some apps to Electron (with Angular), but first question I faced is - "where is new BrowserWindow" function? I need modify this function, for example change "contextIsolation", allow to open DevTools and other features.
This is Angular, and I can not even clearly locate place of this function. I use Windows, my current project folder is E:\Angular\AngularElectron\AngularElectron, and Elecron engine unexpectedly started from folder E:\Angular\node-modules... despite I clearly install Electron as
 npm install --save-dev electron

And Electron engine started as EXE file.

Electron started as
 npx electron

But I can not understand - where is function 'new BrowserWindow()' (I have modified it when I worked with Electron without Angular). And I can not understand how I can open DevTools in this case, in my previous application with Electron I have opened DevTools and can see various troubles of my application in DevTools, for example

But now, with Angular, I can not see anything (because DevTools disabled) and even can not found function where main Windows has created. Can anybody explain me this troubles?

Nobody answered me, but I found this issue. I see on the screen just default application, not application what I creating now. For example if I going to absolute random directory in my computer and start in that directory
npx electron

I will receive exactly this case - Only standard Electron welcome page. This is one point.
Second point - with Electron need already check package.json - is it present in package.json and (!main point!) in node-modules folder "electron"?
in my case in node-modules was present only "electron-to-chromium".
As I understand after investigation - this issue is happens if global Angular version different than local.
This is correct Angular Electron project setting https://github.com/Alex1998100/AngularElectron
